# Trying to loop through numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying open a text document and put the data into a array. This is fine, but when I'm trying to loop through the array and search for where the `array[][2] is >=1` for more than 100 samples the code fail. I have never used numpy before but the amount of data that the script have to search through may be up to a million lines of data on a Rasberry Pi, so I have to write something that is fast.

```
#reads the log data into a array
data = np.genfromtxt(('tilfeldigetall.txt'),dtype= 'float', delimiter="")
for i in np.nditer(data, flags=['external_loop']):
    # checks if the Z axis has been stable for more then 100 samples. 
    if all(data[i][2] >= 1 for a in np.nditer(100, flags=['external_loop'])):
          # Gathers the data from when it's stable and 10 sec back in time
          for n in reversed(2700):
                    Ax = data[i-n][0]
                    Ay = data[i-n][1]
                    Az = data[i-n][2]
                    #calculate angle from acc
                    delta = (Az/sqrt(((Ax*Ax)+(Ay*Ay)+(Az*Az))))
                    AanchorAngle = math.atan(delta)
                    AanchorAngle =math.degrees(AanchorAngle)
                    AanchorAngle = abs(AanchorAngle)
```

The error message is

> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: What is this line doing: `reversed(2700)`. Reversed needs an iterable sequence, not an integer.

Comment: My tough was that it counts from 2700 to 0, so that I get the data i the right order. Lower "n" means further back in time.

Comment: Then you probably want `reversed(range(2701))`.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, could the main problem be that numpy handles if all different from standard python? And therefor the code fails.

Comment: `np.nditer` iterates over `data`. instead of using `data[i]`, you can use `i` directly